# How can I output before the final clearpage using AtEndDocument or similar?

Tags: hooks

I would like to output a single line of text at the end of all the documents generated using a particular coustom package file. I assumed `\AtEndDocument` would do the trick as I have used it before to do things like closing environments that were automatically opened at the start of the document, etc. Si I tried this:

```
\AtEndDocument{%
    \textit{my note here}
}
```

But this seems to output *after* a final `\clearpage` or similar has been run on the document and the line appears on a page of it's own. This is now what I want.

To my surprise trying to search for this, several questions around this site and the net seem to be asking for just the opposite: how to issue commands *after* the clear-page. It seems the behaviour I'm seing is what other people want and vise versa.

How can I add a snippet to the end of a document that ends on the same page with the rest of the content?

Comment: It doesn't happen for me. The text is not on a page of its own. Make a complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In trying to put together a MWE I found the culprit, see my answer. Thanks for forcing me to try this outside of my full environment.

Comment: There's also [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) which provides a host of hooks for the end-of-document area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `\AtEndDocument` itself, the problem is a package that has messed with that hook.

In my case I was using the package [`lastpage`](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage/lastpage.pdf). Moving the `\usepackage{lastpage}` declaration to the end of my package file *after* I had declared what I wanted to have in that hook caused my snippet to appear on the proper page.

Comment: Thanks, that's my issue too. The same happens with the newer (?) `pageslts` as well. Since I can't (in good conscience) move the package load to the end of my preamble (I have modular documents), I opted for a manual `\AtEndDocument{\label{LastPage}}` -- now it's fine. (There may be corner cases in which the label does not end up on the last page -- I guess I'll deal with that when I encounter it.)

Answer (score 0):

At https://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage the manual for the lastpage package is available.

The version at the time of this post is v2.0a, its manual reads:

> Subsection 3.1 `\AtEndDocument`
>
> **`\AtEndDocument` is not used by the lastpagemodern.sty version of the lastpage package, requiring LaTeX-format 2022-11-01 or newer. Instead `\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}` is used and the problem does not arise.**
>
> lastpageclassic.sty uses `\AtEndDocument` and lastpage209.sty redefines
> `\enddocument`. The last two cases are problematic: The output of a
> LaTeX2e run is not independent of the order in which the packages are
> loaded. It is often the case that the same formats for which one must
> put tables and figure at the end, are the ones in which endnotes are
> also required. If one wants to use `\AtEndDocument` here as well (as
> done for `\pageref{LastPage}`), then it is easy to get to three separate
> uses of `\AtEndDocument` (assuming one uses this for the endnotes as
> well). Clearly it is not safe for any package writer or user to assume
> that no material will follow what they put into `\AtEndDocument`.
> Therefore a message, which begins with AED, is included in every usage
> of `\AtEndDocument`. lastpage uses `\AtEndDocument{...\clearpage...}`,
> thus `\usepackage{lastpage}...\AtEndDocument{something}` will place
> something after the `\clearpage`. To place it earlier, use
> `\AtEndDocument{something}...\usepackage{lastpage}`. If the something is
> not known before `\usepackage{lastpage}`, you can use for example

```
...
\def\beforeLastpageClearpage{\relax}
\AtEndDocument{\beforeLastpageClearpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
...
\def\beforeLastpageClearpage{\textit{something}}%
...
\end{document}
```

> (might need a protected and/or expanded `\def`). When
> `\clearpage` leads to some output, `\clearpage\textit{something}` instead
> of `\textit{something}` might be wanted.

**tl;dr**

Either use LaTeX-format 2022-11-01 or newer (`\usepackage{lastpage}` automatically loads the modern style which does not even use `\AtEndDocument` but `\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}`)

or pay attention where/when to `\AtEndDocument` your stuff.